# Why am I getting segmentation fault in my while loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

My program will read the datas from a txt into my structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct competitor
{
    int id;
    char* name;
    char* nationality;
    char* sex;
    double weight;
    char* event;
}competitor;

int sportolok_beolvas(char* filename, competitor* array)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r"); 
    int n = 0; 

    while(fscanf(file, "%d %s %s %s %lf %s", &array[n].id, array[n].name, array[n].nationality, array[n].sex, &array[n].weight, array[n].event) == 6)
    {
        ++n;
    }
    fclose(file);

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    competitor* array;
    int i = sportolok_beolvas("sportolok.txt", array);
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

I did this function based on my previous project, which uses almost the same function. Read in the file to my struct. I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: You have not allocated memory to `array`.

Comment: You have plenty of pointers. None of them have been initialized to actually point anywhere. Dereferencing them in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: But I don't want it to be a dynamic array. Or that's the only way to do it?

Comment: Because they are strings. Every char* is a string in my program, as far as I know they don't have to point anywhere. At least that's how they taught us.

Comment: "[T]hey don't have to point anywhere..." Then you have been taught wrong. A pointer is really what the name implies: It's something which points somewhere else. If you don't make a pointer to actually point somewhere valid, it's unusable.

Comment: And C never had any kind of dynamic arrays. You need to handle all such things yourself explicitly in the code, with e.g. `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: I know that a pointer have to point somewhere. But then how am I supposed to mark a string? That's how the prof taught us. If I have to create a string then " char* string;" this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Where I learn it, they call it dynamic array if we have to use a malloc, calloc or realloc

Comment: That char* string could be pointing anywhere in memory. The memory not allocated should not be read/write.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to do it? Because as I see, I can throw my knowledge about strings to the bin ://

Comment: You already got an answer. But if you wish to use character pointers, then declare an array, something like **buffer[MAX];** and then assign it's address to the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string is really an array of characters with a null-terminator at the end.

You can create a string using plain arrays, like

```
char str[] = "foo";
```

Or you can use pointers and allocate memory dynamically, like

```
char *str = malloc(4);
strcpy(str, "foo");
```

Both those examples are almost equivalent (there are some important differences between arrays and pointers, but lets put those aside for now). Both those examples creates a string with three characters (plus the null-terminator).

However, if you have

```
char *str;
strcpy(str, "foo");
```

then you have *undefined behavior* because the pointer `str` doesn't point anywhere.

---

Going back to your code, the simplest solution for the strings are simply to change them from pointers to arrays:

```
#define NAME_SIZE        20
#define NATIONALITY_SIZE 20
#define SEX_SIZE         10
#define EVENT_SIZE       20

typedef struct competitor
{
    int id;
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char nationality[NATIONALITY_SIZE];
    char sex[SEX_SIZE];
    double weight;
    char event[EVENT_SIZE];
}competitor;
```

As for the array of `competitor` structures, I recommend you create it dynamically as needed inside the loop, reallocating as needed.

Read into a single defined `competitor` structure object, and copy it to the current array element.

Once done return the pointer to the first element of the array.

Perhaps something like this:

```
// Out dynamic "array", pointer to its first element
competitor *competitors = NULL;

// Current size of the competitor array
size_t current_size = 0;

// A structure object to store the data we read from the input
competitor current_competitor;

// Now the loop to read the data
while(fscanf(file, "%d %s %s %s %lf %s",
             &current_competitor.id,
             current_competitor.name,
             current_competitor.nationality,
             current_competitor.sex,
             &current_competitor.weight,
             current_competitor.event) == 6)
{
    // Reallocate the array, adding one new element (+1)
    // If the array doesn't exist, when competitors is NULL, create
    // an array with a single element
    competitor *new_array = realloc(competitors, sizeof *new_array * current_size + 1);

    // Check if the allocation succeeded or failed
    if (new_array == NULL)
    {
        // TODO: Report it
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Make the new array our actual array
    competitors = new_array;

    // Copy the the structure object we just have read, into the array
    competitors[current_size] = current_competitor;

    // And finally increase the size
    ++current_size;
}

After this, the `competitors` pointer will point to the first element of an array of `current_size` elements.

Exactly how to return these values (*both* needs to be returned) is left as an exercise for the reader.
```